# friedman-post-hoc-test R code

Tags: r

I found the R code for this post-hoc test here: https://www.r-statistics.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/Friedman-Test-with-Post-Hoc.r.txt

But if I copy paste this whole code, I get "+" signs in the console screen and I can't execute any command anymore. I'm really a layperson when it comes to R so I don't know if I'm doing it right by copy en pasting the code?

Comment: I can't reproduce this: everything works for me.

Comment: So you also just copy past the whole code and run all the lines?

Comment: the + sign means the code is incomplete.  Most likely missing a closing ) or }

Comment: It's like the formula is already installed because when I start to type friedman, I get the option "friedman.test.with.post.hoc {.GlobalEnv}. But if I execute the commad I get following error: "evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"

Comment: I'd recommend to simply save this file as an R script and then `source` it.